# When two adjectives need two different indefinite articles

Tags: adjectives, american-english, articles

What do you do when two adjectives require different indefinite articles?

Is this sentence correct:
"Here is an easy and fun way to accomplish the task."

Normally, "fun" would take the article "a" in front of it, not "an."

So do I have to write
"Here is an easy and a fun way to accomplish the task"
instead?

Answer (score 5):

You’d place an indefinite article before the first adjective only, thus “an easy and fun way” or “a fun and easy way”; if you wish to add more adjectives, try rephrasing, i.e., “here are easy, fun and interesting ways...”